# Unity C#: How can I create a GameObject at screen position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen

Unity is so difficult compared to delphi. In delphi you can just say:

```
Rectangle1.Position.Y := 0;
Rectangle1.Position.X := screen.Width - Rectangle1.Width;
```

This will just change the position of the Rectangle to the top right corner of the screen. But in Unity there's so much to learn just to do this and I don't know where I start. Can someone please simplify this to me? I just want create a object at the top right corner of the screen, both in smartphones and pcs.

I'm using Unity2D

EDIT: This is the Inspector of the object that I want to create:
[image]

And this is the code that I use to create Objects on the screen:

`Instantiate(objectName, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);`

EDIT to be more clear: [image]

Comment: You're talking about a 3D cube here? Or some kind of GUI element?

Comment: What language? C# or Unityscript? Update the tag with somethiing you have tried.

Comment: Just a image in png "converted" to prefab.
I use this to instantiate the object:

`Instantiate(tileVerde1, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);`

Comment: If you're dealing with gameobjects, the `transform.position` property is a settable Vector3. Simply create a new position `var pos = new Vector3(x,y,z)` and assign it.

Comment: Sorry, your question is too broad.1.Explain what you are doing. 2.You need to add that code to your question to let people know what you have tried. You also need to explain if the prefab image is a SpriteRenderer or a UI component. If you are not sure, upload screenshot of what components are attached to the prefab you are instantiating. This will help us answer your question. You should also include tag about the language you are working on. The title is wrong too. Finally tell what the result you are getting and what you expect.

Comment: I updated my question with more information, thanks guys.

Comment: Much more better!

Comment: Can you explain what that Image is used for? I think that I might have a better solution.

Comment: This image make part of the ground where the the player will be able to build rails. When I put the position x = 0 and y = 0 the tile is created on the center of the screen.

This image will ilustrate better: https://scontent.fmgf1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/15841254_1542948989063619_986763702_n.png?oh=101c38dbe6610518bc1a99bbac4bca91&oe=586BF885

And this is why I want to know how can I put the image on the top left of the screen. If I put just one tile there I can build all the other based on his position, because I know his height/width = 0.9f;

Comment: Another solution that I thought was to move the camera a little bit to the bottom/right. But how much? This is the question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The screen coordinate of the camera is not the same as the world coordinate (one has 2 dimensions & the other has 3. One uses pixels & the other Unity units).

I would use [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Qouting the docs :

> Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(position: Vector3) Transforms position from screen space into world space.
>
> Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight). The z position is in world units from the camera.

So to put your Rectangle on the corner in a similar way to what you described (with pseudocode C# mix):

```
Vector3 p = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, Screen.height, HowFarFromCamera));
Rectangle1.position = new Vector3(p.x + Rectangle1.Width/2,p.y - Rectangle1.Height/2,p.z);
```

Point **p** is the corner in world coordinate (which is the important thing). I shifted by Width/2 and Height/2 assuming that your rectangle's pivot is in the middle.

Note: You can use [Bounds.size](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-size.html) to get the width or height (a struct available for both Renderer & SpriteRenderer)

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion I'd give you since you seem to be working exclusively with 2D (looking at your other posts) is to look for Unity UI system (which was released in 4.6 : many people refer to it as UI 4.6) :

- You can find a lot of informations [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) about the **Canvas** and other UI Components.
- [Here](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) you'll find the basic tutorials to get started with it.

The idea is you can anchor your objects inside a **Canvas** : in your situation you'll only have to anchor an **Image** to the desired corner and then to offset it by half its width/height (you can also set the object pivot point to the right corner and anchor it to the matching corner without having to offset it).